# How to make a route unique

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, url-routing

I use asp.net 4 c# and routing.

I have two routes, as you can see I pass to arguments for each route `{ContentId}` and `{TitleUrl}`, please pay attention at the first part `article/` and `blog/`.

Here an example of correct resulted

```
mysite.com/article/150/my-special-article
mysite.com/blog/25/my-special-blogpost
```

If a User try to manipulate the URL changing `article/` and `blog/` section, the route continue to display the content.

```
   mysite.com/article/150/my-special-article // same page
   mysite.com/somtheingelsehere/150/my-special-article // same page
```

My web site at the moment continue to display the content, but I need some sort of validation and make sure that my requested URL is as specified in the route or I would show a 404 page.

Any idea how could solve it? (I hope guys I was able to explain in properly, if you need more clarificaiton please let me know). Thanks!

---

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ArticleDetails", "article/{ContentId}/{TitleUrl}", "~/ContentDetails.aspx");

routes.MapPageRoute("BlogPostDetails", "blog/{ContentId}/{TitleUrl}", "~/ContentDetails.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is either use different pages for articles and blog posts, or in ContentDetails.aspx check for the correct URL accordingly.

```
if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/blog/") && postType = "blog") ...
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot make point to a different page, I will consider your option thanks